# Calling yahoo request_auth endpoint for OIDC SSO yields 'uh oh'

Tags: yahoo-oauth

I'm trying to login a user to yahoo using an OIDC RP using a redirect like this:

> `https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?response_type=code&client_id=(snip)&state=001520551248694Xjr6KF2IV&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyhostname.com%3A9444%2Foidcclient%2Fredirect%2FRP&scope=openid`

After a successful login, the user gets this from yahoo:

> Uh oh Looks like something went wrong. Please try again later.

I don't get the consent screen and I never get a redirect back.  My initial redirect to yahoo for the login is the last thing that I can see in my trace.

I saw in another post that the redirect must match my YDN app's callback domain.  The hostname in my redirect does match my callback domain. However, the value for the redirect parameter does not match since my uri is not just https:// (hostname).

- Is there some way that I can find out what the 'something' is that went
  wrong so that I can try to fix it?
- If it **is** the redirect URI, how do I go about getting in touch with yahoo to find out if it is possible to have them support full uris?
  -- The redirect uri should be a uri, not just a hostname (which is a urn).  YDN wouldn't accept a port and it wouldn't accept a path.
  -- Our runtime, and therefore our customers, cannot interoperate with yahoo if actual uris are not supported for the redirect_uri.

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is document how our customers can configure our RP to work with yahoo's OP and I can't make it work.  Am I doing something that is obviously incorrect?  (besides the redirect)

Comment: I thought that it may have something to do with my scope since I was get the error before the auth screen comes up.  My original scope was openid+profile.  I don't see 'profile' as being supported by yahoo, so I changed to just 'openid'.  I went back and used 'openid,mail-r' (openid%2Cmail-r encoded), which they have explicitly in their doc.  No dice.

Comment: From what I gather Yahoo does not support "Open ID **CONNECT**", they do support OpenID (different from Open ID Connect). I've had the same problem for MONTHS now. (I know they have at least one article about it -- but that's just theory. I was just doing an internet search to see if they have PERHAPS, finally implemented it, when I discovered your question.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm running into a similar issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I didn't not figure it out.